# Given any polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$ we can have a corresponding matrix with characteristic polynomial equal to the given polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Proposition: Any polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $(-1)^n$ is the characteristic polynomial of some linear operator.

I do not want to construct an 'explicit matrix' corresponding to the polynomial $(-1)^n(\lambda_n x^n+\cdots+ \lambda_0)$. However, I want to use induction to prove the existence holds. However, I have no idea since generally the polynomial is not necessary reducible. Can anyone give any hint?

Answer (score 3):

You may get an idea from [Companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The direct proof is not hard. Try with a matrix with a lower diagonal identity and with your polynomial coefficients (in suitable order) in the last column.