# Establish if True or False: Any polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $(-1)^n$ is the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

This is an exercise from *Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel*.

The question asks to determine if True or False: Any polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $(-1)^n$ is the characteristic polynomial of some linear operator.

I know that it is true after scouring the internet and trying to understand how to prove the result, but this is where I'm having trouble. From the different material I've read it says that the result can be proven by induction. How is the induction actually working? The following is where I run astray:

Take a polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $(-1)^n$. That gives us
$$(-1)^{n}(a_0 + a_{1}t + \dots a_{n}t^{n})$$.

Right now this is just a general polynomial. The only notions that stick out to me as being indicative of a polynomial being the characteristic polynomial of a linear operator is by

1. calculating the characteristic polynomial explicitly for the linear operator by the $\det(T-\lambda I)$ process
2. The Cayley Hamilton Theorem (which I just learned about in the chapter I'm working on):  $f(T) = T_{0}$ where $f(t)$ is the characteristic polynomial and $T_{0}$ is the zero linear operator.

Out of those two ideas the one that seems it could be most viable would be the Cayley Hamilton, but that would mean I need to assume that the polynomial is a characteristic polynomial Which is what I'm trying to prove.

There was another question posted on this years ago: [Given any polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$ we can have a corresponding matrix with characteristic polynomial equal to the given polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219462/given-any-polynomial-of-degree-n-geq-1-we-can-have-a-corresponding-matrix-wit)

but the hints in that refer to the companion matrix, something I haven't encountered before.

How could I do the induction proof correctly? Or better how should I set things up because I feel that's where the problem is.

Comment: Are you talking about real/complex/integer/other coefficients? and linear map on what field?

Comment: From the tone of the text it appears it would be over any field.

Comment: Leading coefficient of $(-1)^n$ means the polynomial is of the form $(-1)^nt^n + a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\dots + a_1t+a_0$, no? I think the second answer of the linked question should solve it.

Comment: That is my problem. I've never encountered the companion matrix and don't know how to solve it with that idea.

Comment: Try just calculating (the hard way) the characteristic polynomial of the companion matrix, based on the definition on wikipedia.

Comment: If you have any exposure to abstract algebra, then you could construct a suitable operator by considering the multiplication operator $q(t) \mapsto tq(t)$ over the quotient space 
$$
V = \Bbb F[t]/\langle p(t) \rangle
$$
where $p(t)$ is the characteristic polynomial. We can show that this transformation $A$ has the desired characteristic polynomial by noting that $q(A) = 0$ if and only if $p(t)$ divides $q(t)$.

Comment: Too advanced for me at this stage @BenGrossmann , I'm taking the suggestion of Sam, and I'm at least starting to see the pattern. Turns out a few of the questions that I skipped in a section earlier actually pertain to recognizing the characteristic polynomial. Specifically I had to show the characteristic polynomial of A is a polynomial of degree $n$ with leading coefficient $(-1)^n$. So it was the converse of this.